# How to sum mysql values in multple while PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i like to sum all row values from the $orderfeed_query. But when i echo the $sum, i get just the sum from the last loop.

how can can i add the sum of all following loop on the $sum variable? I dont know how many loops a order have.

```
$checkorder = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE  `email` = '$email' ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkorder)) {
    $orderid = $row["orderid"];
    $check_order = $row["check_order"];

    if($check_order[0] == 1){

        $orderfeed_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderfeed WHERE `orderid` = '$orderid' AND `product` = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderfeed_query)) {
            $signaturewiz = $row["signaturewiz"];
            $flurstueckwiz = $row["flurstueckwiz"];
            $uploadwiz = $row["uploadwiz"];
            $exsignaturewiz = $row["exsignaturewiz"];
            $ibanwiz = $row["ibanwiz"];

            $sum = $signaturewiz+$flurstueckwiz+$uploadwiz+$exsignaturewiz+$ibanwiz;

            echo $sum;

        }
    }   

}
}
```

Comment: You should define `$sum` outside of the loop, you're just overriding it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
$sum = $signaturewiz + $flurstueckwiz + $uploadwiz + $exsignaturewiz + $ibanwiz;
```

overwrites sum each time. You must add to sum not to overwrite

```
$sum += $signaturewiz + $flurstueckwiz + $uploadwiz + $exsignaturewiz + $ibanwiz;
```

And declare `$sum = 0;` before main loop

Comment: echo $sum; must be outside the loop not in the loop

Comment: Right now you have echo 1 and echo 2 which gives you 1 and 2 which is 12 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Move the echo of `$sum` outside the loop

Use `+=` rather than `+` to accumulate a total over multiple iterations

Initialize your variable before using `+=` as if `$sum` has an undefined value it can mess up the count when using `+=`

```
    $sum = 0;   // init variable
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderfeed_query)) {
        $signaturewiz = $row["signaturewiz"];
        $flurstueckwiz = $row["flurstueckwiz"];
        $uploadwiz = $row["uploadwiz"];
        $exsignaturewiz = $row["exsignaturewiz"];
        $ibanwiz = $row["ibanwiz"];

        $sum += $signaturewiz + $flurstueckwiz + $uploadwiz + 
                $exsignaturewiz + $ibanwiz;
    }
    echo $sum;
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:

You see 12 and not 3 so the data from your table I assume is text and not numeric so do this to convert text numbers to integers

```
    $sum = 0;   // init variable
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderfeed_query)) {
        $signaturewiz   = (int)$row["signaturewiz"];
        $flurstueckwiz  = (int)$row["flurstueckwiz"];
        $uploadwiz      = (int)$row["uploadwiz"];
        $exsignaturewiz = (int)$row["exsignaturewiz"];
        $ibanwiz        = (int)$row["ibanwiz"];

        $sum += $signaturewiz + $flurstueckwiz + $uploadwiz + 
                $exsignaturewiz + $ibanwiz;
    }
    echo $sum;
```

Comment: You do want to get the total of ALL the columns in ALL the rows in your result set, Right? Or am I confused

Comment: i like to sum all values of the rows:   $signaturewiz = $row["signaturewiz"];
        $flurstueckwiz = $row["flurstueckwiz"];
        $uploadwiz = $row["uploadwiz"];
        $exsignaturewiz = $row["exsignaturewiz"];
        $ibanwiz = $row["ibanwiz"];, the result of the first order is 1 the second is 2. but i see just 12 not 3.

Comment: See additional Info RE: Non numeric data from the database

Answer (score 1):

Several people have pointed out that `$sum` should be outside the loop, and that is indeed correct. However, MySQL can do this all for you:

```
    $orderfeed_query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(signaturewiz + flurstueckwiz + uploadwiz + exsignaturewiz + ibanwiz) FROM orderfeed WHERE orderid = '$orderid' AND product = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($orderfeed_query)) {
        echo $row[0];
    }
```

Comment: @Gimo You've posted the same comment to all three answers. That kinda makes me think the actual sum of all the fields in the selection really is 12. What happens when you `var_dump($row);print "<hr/>"; ' in place of the `echo()` in your original example?

Comment: array(16) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["orderid"]=> string(10) "1468863981" ["product"]=> string(1) "1" ["check_order"]=> string(5) "11100" ["productamount"]=> string(2) "39" ["strasse"]=> string(9) "Ackerstr." ["hausnummer"]=> string(1) "1" ["plz"]=> string(5) "32051" ["ort"]=> string(7) "Herford" ["koordinaten"]=> string(0) "" ["regionalschluessel"]=> string(0) "" ["signaturewiz"]=> string(1) "1" ["flurstueckwiz"]=> string(1) "0" ["uploadwiz"]=> string(1) "0" ["exsignaturewiz"]=> string(1) "0" ["ibanwiz"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: and array(16) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["orderid"]=> string(10) "1470041156" ["product"]=> string(1) "1" ["check_order"]=> string(5) "10000" ["productamount"]=> string(2) "39" ["strasse"]=> string(13) "Aachener Str." ["hausnummer"]=> string(1) "1" ["plz"]=> string(5) "10178" ["ort"]=> string(6) "Berlin" ["koordinaten"]=> string(0) "" ["regionalschluessel"]=> string(0) "" ["signaturewiz"]=> string(1) "1" ["flurstueckwiz"]=> string(1) "0" ["uploadwiz"]=> string(1) "1" ["exsignaturewiz"]=> string(1) "0" ["ibanwiz"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: when a wiz have a "1" it is activate a message and i like to sum all new messages, it works by 1 orderid but not by multiple orderids